# adding zero/Nan rows to discontinuous index in pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I am stuck with a process where I have pandas dataframe which has one of its columns as my desired index.

But this index has a Str+num type.

```
Index_H

['N0000', 'N0002', 'N0003', 'N0007', 'N0011', 'N0017', 'N0018', 'N0020', 'N0021', 'N0023', 'N0026', 'N0027', 'N0028', 'N0030', 'N0033', 'N0034', 'N0045', 'N0050', 'N0052', 'N0055', 'N0056', 'N0057', 'N0059']
```

Each of these Index Values has an associated row of values spanning to 344 columns (1*344) for each N****
I want to convert this to a continuous index and add zeros/Nan to the rows where the index is missing.

Comment: build a serise string and reindex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'foo': ['one','one','two','two','two'],
                       'bar': [ 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C'],
                       'baz': [ 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]},index=['N0001','N0004','N0005','N0006','N0009'])
idx='N'+pd.Series(list(range(1,11))).astype(str).str.zfill(4)
df2.reindex(idx)

Out[365]: 
       bar  baz  foo
N0001    B  2.0  one
N0002  NaN  NaN  NaN
N0003  NaN  NaN  NaN
N0004    C  3.0  one
N0005    A  4.0  two
N0006    B  5.0  two
N0007  NaN  NaN  NaN
N0008  NaN  NaN  NaN
N0009    C  6.0  two
N0010  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. But for both your solution, and the one above I get the same error. " raise ValueError("cannot reindex from a duplicate axis") ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis "

Comment: @KamalanathanG the error , give back to you means the index have duplicate ,which is not allowed,try to using unique value setting up the index

Comment: I merged the duplicated index with rows and later your solution work like a charm Thanks!

Comment: @KamalanathanG Yw~ , nice day

Comment: The `reindex` solution from @Zero is simpler and easier.

Answer (score 2):

Using `reindex`

```
In [350]: df
Out[350]:
       a
N0000  1
N0002  2
N0003  3
N0007  4

In [358]: df.reindex(['N%04d' % x for x in range(int(df.index[-1][1:])+1)])
Out[358]:
         a
N0000  1.0
N0001  NaN
N0002  2.0
N0003  3.0
N0004  NaN
N0005  NaN
N0006  NaN
N0007  4.0
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. But for both your solution, and the one below I get the same error.
" raise ValueError("cannot reindex from a duplicate axis")

ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis "